# Is there any way to make audio spectrum hollow in After Effects?

Tags: layers, shapes, effects, adobe-after-effects

I'm trying to make it look like this:[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the Audio Spectrum control panel you'll find **Inside Color**, **Outside Color**, **Thickness** and **Softness**. Adjust those until you get the result you want. You can [watch a demonstration here](https://motionworks.net/effects-audio-spectrum/).

[image]

Comment: What if I'm trying to achieve transparency?

Comment: Use a blending mode or alpha channel https://helpx.adobe.com/search.html#q=create%20alpha%20channel&t=All&sort=relevancy&f:@CommonProduct=[After%20Effects]&CommonProduct=After%20Effects

Comment: Still can't figure it out...